How to express the reverse of a Many-to-One in Django
I realized that Django has Many-to-One and not One-to-Many, but how to you express the opposite relationship?
I have a table which has 2 foreign keys to another table.  The table Validation_Run has 2 foreign keys to Calibration_Run  Django complains that that the reverse relationship has a conflict
calibration.ValidationRun.calibration_run_pk: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'CalibrationRun.validationrun_set' for 'calibration.ValidationRun.calibration_run_pk' clashes with reverse accessor for 'calibration.ValidationRun.calibration_run_pk_tune_parameters'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'calibration.ValidationRun.calibration_run_pk' or 'calibration.ValidationRun.calibration_run_pk_tune_parameters'.
How do I define the reverse relationship (from Calibration_Run to Validation_Run), so there is no conflict?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%28fields.E304%29+Reverse+accessor

Django has both Many-to-One and One-to-Many, but One-to-Many is only available as an implicit consequence of Many-to-One. When you create a Many-to-One using ForeignKey, Django creates the reverse relationship (which will be a One-to-Many) automatically, and it also names them automatically. But it doesn't account for multiple relationships between the same models, so there will be a naming conflict. @neverwalkaloner's answer gives you the solution for how to account for that & avoid the naming conflict manually.

You shoule specify different related_name for these foreign key fields. Something like this:
field = models.ForeignKey(related_name="calibrations")
field2 = models.ForeignKey(related_name="calibrations2")

